# File monitoring on a shared host

Tags: shell, monitoring, host

I've got a client that wants to be notified anytime there are new files in their directory on a shared host. Since the directory is a website, which caches files to a specific subdirectory, we want to be able to ignore changes to that subdirectory.

Is there a tool that can do this already? Or a shell script?

It would be great if the results could be emailed as well.

Comment: Telling what OS you run would help.

Comment: Yes, this can be done but the implementation is OS, and possibly even filesystem, dependent.

Answer (score 0):

If possible,, use [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=why&lang=en). It uses Linux kernel inotify feature (which basically sends signals to user-space every time some wanted file/directory is altered) and can be configured for example to run a script every time some file or directory is somehow modified or accessed. With incron you can get the alerts in real time.

Comment: And what if it's not a Linux machine?

Comment: Then we'll think again. :-) I'm betting in this case this is about Linux.